# Binding arrow keys in GNU Screen

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnu-screen

I'm a newcomer to GNU Screen and so far I'm liking it. However there is something I can't quite get to work the way I could in tmux.

I want to make it so that Ctrl-a "arrow key" changes **focus** between my windows. I typically have many splits in my terminal window.

I've searched around but been unable to find a config that works. Note I do not want to switch between windows, just the focus.

Bonus points if someone could explain the difference between "bind" and "bindkey" to my addled brain.

Cheers

Comment: bind binds a command to a key.  bindkey manages the input translation tables. These are tables that determine how Screen reacts to certain sequences of characters. https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Key-Binding.html

Answer (score 11):

Since `:bind` will not accept weird virtual characters like the arrow-keys — only keypresses that have ASCII-codes or stuff like <kbd>ctrl</kbd>*<kbd>thingThatHasAsciiCode</kbd>* — I think using `:bindkey` is the simplest way to get what you're after. For me, the following worked under GNU screen 4.06.01 in xterm and could be added either into "~/.screenrc" (affects just you) or "/etc/screenrc" (meant to apply system-wide):

```
# ctrlA then right-arrow-key jumps active cursor one pane to the right:
bindkey "^A^[OC" focus right

# ctrlA then left-arrow-key jumps active cursor one pane to the left:
bindkey "^A^[OD" focus left

# ctrlA then up-arrow-key jumps active cursor one pane above current:
bindkey "^A^[OA" focus up

# ctrlA then up-arrow-key jumps active cursor one pane below current:
bindkey "^A^[OB" focus down
```

Depending on your terminal and settings, *the codes you need to place after the* "^A" *may be different for you*. To determine what these codes are, I prefer to use `vim`; open it and then press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter edit-mode, then press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> to take raw input, then hit the key or key-combination in question * **.

When you use my approach, you'll need to type your <kbd>ctrl</kbd>*<kbd>arrowKey</kbd>* command fairly swiftly; `screen` stops listening for custom bindings if you pause for too long between keystrokes. If it's expiring too quickly, use `:bindkey -t` instead of `:bindkey` to disable the timer.

* Note that ***unlike*** in `vim`, screen will not like it if you insert the *actual* metacharacter escapes into ".screenrc" or other files you might source; simply use literal, individual '^' and '[', not the weird combined version that `vim` can output (at least, that seemed to screw things up for me).

** Some people determine special key-codes by running `cat` (by itself) in the terminal, and then pressing the key(s) in question (before using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to quit). I don't use this approach so YMMV.

Comment: +1 for the `vim` trick, this is truly wonderful, it seems to work with any key combination I tried so far (Alt+arrows, Ctrl+arrows, and so on). Thanks a million !

Comment: Typo for left arrow ascii code, should be `"^A^[OD"`, other than that, works perfect, thx !

Comment: @Gluck Fixed! And glad it was helpful.